# How can I use handlebars-helpers library in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, assemble

I use currently [hbs](https://github.com/donpark/hbs) as template engine in express.js. I think the [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) library very useful.

But I have no idea how I can integrate this library.
I also don't find a description for usage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install it:

```
$ npm i handlebars-helpers
```

Next, add this to your Express app (probably before the template engine configuration):

```
var Handlebars = require('hbs').handlebars;
require('handlebars-helpers').register(Handlebars, {});
```

This will only work if your app directory contains a `package.json` file (which may contain an empty object, `{}`, but is does have to exist).

Comment: Ok thanks, that with package.json I have not yet understood. Otherwise everythings works after I've cleaned up my project of pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's pretty straight forward. Copy the `lib` folder [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/tree/master/lib) and add the `handsontable.js` to your project when you need it.

They show you how to use it in the [index.js](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/index.js) file in the lib folder.

```
//Usage    
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
```